# Which answer do you accept in this situation? (Using someones answer to create a better self-answer)

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, self-answer

I asked this question: [How to use a socket created by root with a normal user](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58281963/6699433)

The user P.Dmitry gave a very useful answer that solved the issue for me. After that, I used his answer to construct something a bit better. At least for my needs.

Of course, I upvoted his answer, but which should be accepted? It does not feel good to accept my own answer in this situation, but at the same time, it does suit my needs better and does in general answer the question better.

How should I do in this situation? Or should I even have done something different earlier?

Comment: As long as you have acknoweldged the other user's input the choice of "acceptance" is entirely yours as the Asker

Comment: Let's say you do "the right thing" and you pick the answer which best helped you - your own in this case. What is the worst thing that can happen? It is going to be possible that the author of the original answer is going to call you out on it, maybe even be upset about it. Does that possibility bother you? If so, leave things the way they are. If not, then do as you please.

Comment: You could always make your answer community wiki and accept it.

Comment: Why not ping the provider of the good answer and ask if he/she is happy with you making an edit to it - clearly marked as an edit, of course. (Or suggest he/she makes the edit, according to your 'guidance'?)

Comment: Do you really have to accept any answer at all. The same way you can accept any  answer, you can also accept none.

Answer (score -6):

In cases where I don't directly go with the answer but it got me most of the way I normally edit the question with what I decided to do and thank + accept + upvote the answer that led me there.

I do this for 2 reasons, firstly it places all the acknowledgment with the person who answered, and secondly it places your (hopefully better) code near the top.

If the answer has a simple mistake (like the one linked) I correct it and let the answerer know.

#### Edit: What I did

I decided to do it like this, because ... (inspired by user)

```
<code sample>
```

Comment: answers don't belong in the question.